# SQL - Datetime stamp in odd format

Tags: date, timestamp

I have a date timestamp column where the data is in this format - yyyymmddhhmmssED
e.g. 20140617101703ED

I assume the ED designates Eastern Daylight? Regardless, I am unable to perform calculations like Datediff on columns like these. Shouldn't I be able to? If not, how can I format this column such that I will be able to perform calculations with it? I have tried cast, convert, left, but can't seem to get it :/

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: ...and specify which database you're using